# How to grant access to views programatically in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I give a user access rights (select, update, ...) to a set of views at once?

Answer (score 1):

You can this script (not tested)

```
  DECLARE
    targetUser VARCHAR2(200 CHAR);
  BEGIN
    targetUser := 'fooBar';
    FOR Rec IN (SELECT object_name, object_type FROM user_objects WHERE object_type IN ('VIEW')) LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON '||Rec.object_name||' TO ' || targetUser);
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'GRANT SELECT, UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE ON '||Rec.object_name||' TO ' || targetUser;
    END LOOP;
  END;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also (quite misleadingly named) construct in Oracle called `CREATE SCHEMA`. By using this you can group several DB objects into one "entity" to be subject of granting.

Comment: Good hint. I will look into this in the future. For now I need a "quick and dirty" solution though.